# Take over billing in google appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, billing, android-pay

My user A created an app in google appengine. I would like my user B to take over the billing. I then gave user B access to the project and made a payment from his account, but now he cannot change the billing settings. When user B clicks the "Take over billing" link but get:

"You do not have sufficient permissions to make billing changes. Your budget settings could not be saved. For help please contact support. "

The link to customer support just tells me that there is only support for premium accounts :-(

Any suggestions on how to let another user take over the billing?

Comment: Did you give user B "owner" access to Appengine account (under Admin - Permissions)?

Comment: @Peter: No, just developer access. But right now user B _is_ paying the bill but he is not registered as billing administrator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like my billing settings was in a bad state where user B could do the payment without being the billing administrator.

It got solved when I changed user B from a developer to an administrator. Then the "take over billing" button started to work as expected without any error.

Thanks for the info Peter.